# Count images in post then add class if just one

Tags: attachments, count

I'm trying to add a function to my site that will count the number of images attached to a post, and if only one, to add a class to either that `<img>` or to the containing `<a>`.

I think I'm fairly close, but don't have the PHP syntax skills to finish it up. The code I've hacked together, sourced from various threads on the topic, is:

```
/**
 *
 * Single-image posts will receive a separate class name
 *
 */

add_filter( 'the_content', 'single_image_content_filter', 20 );

// Count images in post
function single_image_content_filter( $content ) {

$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post->ID));
$imgcount = count($attachments);

    // If only one attachment, add a new CSS class
    if ( $imgcount === 1 ) {

        global $post;
        $classes = 'single-img'; // separated by spaces, e.g. 'img image-link'

        // check if there are already classes assigned to the anchor, and/or add one via $classes
        if ( preg_match('/<a.*? class=".*?">/', $content) ) {
        $content = preg_replace('/(<a.*? class=".*?)(".*?>)/', '$1 ' . $classes . '$2', $content);
      } else {
        $content = preg_replace('/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" >', $content);
      }

return $content;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you better not use JavaScript for this? Like: $('.post img:first'); for example

Comment: I don't want it to just target the first out of a possible many images. I want it to only add a class if only one image is found.

Comment: You can still do that with JS, something like: if($('.post img').length == 1) { $('.post img').addClass('some-class'); }

Comment: Any way to get me the full code (answer), and where would be the best place to put it?

Comment: Not today, tomorrow I have some time. Maybe another user can work it out?

Comment: I'd really rather do it with PHP (hate enqueueing issues and all that), but if anyone has any full suggestions either way, I'm open to them.

Answer (score 1):

Using @pascalvgemert's suggestion as a starting point, I'm using the following script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var imgCount = jQuery(".single-post #content-left p a").children("img").length;
    if (imgCount == 1) {
    jQuery("img").addClass("lone-image");
    }
});
```

Works like a charm.